# Get State that a College resides in from FB API

Tags: php, facebook-graph-api, facebook-fql

I am working to get the state that a specific college resides in for a certain user. Provided they have authorized the app and I have their info and their school name I have the following (please ignore the fact that Im not cycling through all of their education options). I know I can get a school code from their info but unsure if how to go about getting the state that that school resides in or if it is possible. Any help is appreciated.

```
$facebook = new Facebook(Config::get('facebook'));
$facebook->setAccessToken($user->access_token);

$uid = $facebook->getUser();

if($uid != 0){
    $me = $facebook->api('/me');
    if($me['education'][0]['type'] == "College"){
        education = $me['education'][0]['school']['name'];
    }

    $university_stats = array();
    $university_stats['templatename'] = "education";
    $university_stats['data'] = array();
    $university_stats['data']['university'] = $education;
    $university_stats['data']['name'] = $me['name'];
    $university_stats['data']['state'] = ????;
}
```

Comment: I dont think the education will return the city or state, you can verify here https://developers.facebook.com/tools/explorer/ by setting the api end point me?fields=education

Comment: Thanks for the advice, seems if I get the users school ID from their profile I can submit another query to find the state and town the school is located in